# How to calculate extrema for a given function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, maxima-minima

Assume that $f(x)$ is a function which is infinite many times differentiable and also continuous for every derivative. The function graph is in general not known.

How is it possible to detect extremas?

Till now i thought $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)\neq 0$ just works, but then i saw the following function:

\begin{cases} 
      0 & x= 0 \\
      \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)&x\neq 0 
\end{cases}

For this function it seems to be more tricky to calculate the extrema at $x=0$.  Probably there are more functions which are even more "complex".

This brings me to my question:
What is a general way calculate the extrema of a given function $f(x)$ for which it is only known that it is infinite many times differentiable and that it is continuous?

Thank you

Comment: $f(x) >0$ for all $x\ne 0.$  You can show that $f'(x) <0$ for all $x<0$, and $f'(x) >0$ for all $x >0$ which would indicate a minimum at $x=0.$

Comment: There is no general way.  Only necessary and sufficient conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fermat's test still works for extrema of your function, you just have to calculate the derivative properly. You have probably noticed that for $x\ne 0$ the derivative is always nonzero. However, computing the derivative at 0 using the difference quotient we find 
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=0
$$
Which tells you that this is the only extremum candidate for the smooth function. The first derivative test is what I would then use to conclude that it is a minimum.

Edit: To avoid any potential ambiguity, for a critical point $x_0$, the first derivative test requires examining the sign $f'(x_0-\epsilon)$ and $f'(x_0+\epsilon)$. $f'(x_0-\epsilon)< 0$ and $f'(x_0+\epsilon)> 0$ yields that $x_0$ is a minimum. Vice versa for a local maximum.

In this case,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}
$$
Which is less than 0 for $x<0$ and greater than 0 for $x>0$, allowing our conclusion.

Comment: the first derivative test, at $x=0$, tells you nothing, since that derivative is itself zero at $x=0$.  As is the second and all higher derivatives.

Comment: @MarkFischler I don't follow. On the left of zero the derivative is negative and on the right it is positive, telling you that at 0 the function is at (at least) a local minimum

Comment: The second derivative at $0$ is indeed $\lim_{x \to 0} 2 \frac{\exp(-1/x²)}{x^4} = 0$. So, the correct criterium is that the sign of the derivative flips for an extremum to occur (instead of the second derivative being nonzero). Another example for this criterion is $f(x) = x^4$. This becomes more tricky in higher dimensions.

Comment: @LinAlg right. I learned this criterion as the first derivative test. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstDerivativeTest.html